# Random multinomial sample, with some restrictions

Tags: sampling, multinomial-distribution

Given a list of $k$ non-negative integers $m_i$, $i=1,...,k$, and a positive integer $n$, with $n\ge m +k$, where $m=\sum m_i$. I need to generate $k$ random positive integers $n_i$, such that $\sum n_i = n$, $n_i > m_i$, and $n_i=1$ whenever $m_i=0$.

What's the simplest way of accomplishing this using an ordinary multinomial generator?

Comment: Presuming that the $m_i$ are given nonnegative integers (is this correct?), this question is equivalent to asking for random nonnegative integers $d_i=n_i-m_i-1$ subject to the restriction that $\sum d_i=n-m-k$. How you generate them depends on what distribution you want the $n_i$ to have. So: what distribution is it supposed to be?

Comment: @whuber I don't care much for the distribution, as long as all allowed values have a finite probability. I think that using your $d_i$ doesn't ensure that $n_i=1$ whenever $m_i = 0$.

Comment: @whuber Yes. The $m_i$ are given nonnegative integers.

Comment: So set $d_i=0$ whenever $m_i=0$ and generate the remaining values!

Comment: @whuber Yeah. That's what I ended up doing. I hoped there was a somewhat more elegant solution.

Comment: @whuber If anyone cares to post an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.